# Chrome Extension not showing data from content script

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to perform a super simple task with extensions which is: on click, open popup, find data on page, populate popup fields and ajax that data over to an external script. However, I can't seem to get the script to populate my popup nor log anything in the console nor `alert()` me of anything, which is necessary so I know that I got the correct data. Here's what I'm running:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test ext",
    "description": "Test ext",
    "version": "0.2",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["event.js", "jquery.min.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/*", 
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Auto Order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Order id:<p id="orderid"></p></span>

</body>
</html>
```

**event.js**

```
    var orderid = $( "left post-rel" ).text();
    alert(orderid);
    console.log(orderid);
```

Again, I'm trying to make this as simple as possible. I assume once I understand how to populate `popup.html` fields I'll understand how to ajax that data offsite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background scripts run in their own invisible, empty page page.

Looks like you're trying to make the background script manipulate both the visible tab (it can't, you need a content script) and the popup (you can't*, you need to add `<script>` to the popup itself).

Get a look at the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

*: In principle you can with `chrome.extension.getViews()`, but it's usually not a good idea.

Comment: Not really manipulate, just grab data off of it, so this means I have to make `<script>` part of popup and `event.js` talk to each other? That does not sound too simple

Comment: Not enough even. You can't grab data off a regular tab in the `event.js`. You need a content script for that. Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27477641/934239), it can help.